# Converting a website into a desktop application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, electron

How can I convert my mean stack web application completely into a desktop application I have built the website which is up and running . How can I use electron to convert this website into a desktop application I used nodejs mongodb angular js and express framework to build the website. Is there any way to change it into a desktop application or I have to make it completely from scratch to make a desktop application Please answer thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to simply "convert" a website into an electron application. There are many issues that arise when creating an electron application, that don't occur in "normal" web-design. While you may be able to use a lot of what you already have, there is no getting around creating a new project.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution may be to keep it as a web app and wrap it with electron. You can use something like https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier